# Join works in the rails console, but not the view

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm working in Rails 5. I have two tables with a HABTM relationship: publications and authors. They're connected by a join table, authors_publications.

I'm trying to get the view to list the names of the authors associated with each publication, and it's returning this: 
[the view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3piOM.png)

It's got the number of authors correct, but I want it to print the actual names. When I try this in my console, the join works correctly. Here's the relevant code from my app:

*publication.rb*

```
class Publication < ApplicationRecord

  self.table_name = "publications"

  has_and_belongs_to_many :authors

  scope :sorted, lambda { order("year_published DESC") }
  scope :newest_first, lambda { order("created_at DESC") }
  #scope :search, lambda {|query| where(["name LIKE ?", "%#{{query}}"])
#}

end
```

*author.rb*

```
class Author < ApplicationRecord

  self.table_name = "authors"

  has_and_belongs_to_many :publications

end
```

*index.html.erb*

```
<% @publications.each do |publication| %>
    <h3><%= publication.name %></h3>
    <p><%= publication.citation %></p>
    <p><%= publication.authors.join(" ") %></p>                
<% end %>
```

How do I make this print the author names associated with each publication instead of printing `<Author:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>#`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
<p><%= publication.authors.pluck(:name).join(" ") %></p>
```

Change the `name` column

The clearest way to do it is

```
<p><%= publication.authors.map(&:name).join(" ") %></p>
```

but the first one is more efficient: it returns just names from the database, the latter returns all the fields for the authors table and then iterate over them to have just the name.

Comment: My pleasure Miss ^_^